# Which machine to back up for Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, domain

I have 2 domains. Either of them have 2 domain controllers. So my architecture is: Domain 1. -  DC1, DC2 and SQL Server.             Doman 2.  -  DC3, DC4 and IIS Server so which one these computers I must back up for active directory?

Comment: Just to be clear, with what you have described there is no single computer that contains the information for both domains, so you will need to back up at least 2 machines, one for each domain.

Answer (score 3):

One or more of your domain controllers have a copy of the Global Catalog. Figure out which one(s) have a copy of the GC - one of those should be what you back up.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to do a System State backup of one DC in each domain to be covered, but, given you've got four DCs total, I'd be safe and just back all four up.

Comment: You dont really need to backup the other DC's which are there for other roles like file server, print servers. Just blindly backing up all the DC's is completely illogical & results just in Redundant data.

Answer (score 1):

I would always back up the system state of every domain controller. It doesn't take much storage space (or effort), so why would you consider not doing this? It's a no-brainer to me, and simply not worth the risk for the minimal effort involved.

What if you had replication issues? These aren't always immediately obvious, and could go unnoticed depending upon how proactive the admin is with log checking.

Ask yourself, Are you sure you can recover from a backup of the domain from a single DC? Are you prepared to take that risk, or is it worth spending 30 mins setting up a scheduled job to back up the other DCs?